# highcharts - problemas con fechas

Tags: highcharts

Buenas. Alguien sabe porqué a la hora de Highcharts considera esta fecha:

`[Date.UTC(2016, 06, 6), 14]`

Como **6 de Julio**, cuando debería ser el **6 de Junio**?

Alguna forma de corregirlo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esto es debido que para el objeto Date de javascript el mes 0 es enero, el 1 febrero, asi hasta llegar que el mes 5 es Junio y el 6 es Julio, si quieres que la fecha sea 6 de Junio deberías

**[Date.UTC(2016, 05, 6), 14]**

Comment: Actualmente lo estoy mostrando desde mi base de datos con esto:    echo "[Date.UTC(".date('y,m,d', strtotime($row['fecha_emision']))."),".$row['total_dia']."],"; 

Como podría restar la fecha del mes?

Comment: Deberias parsear $row['fecha_emision'] para poder obtener el año mes y dia y siempre restar 1 al mes